# How to lauch the app in mobile while a button clicked in wear watch?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

i am new in developing android wear applications. I would like to know how to do an action in mobile device by receiving a button click in android wear watch? 
For example a button in wear application to start activity in mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation can happen in two ways..

1.By pressing Action button in a Notification.
2.By pressing a button in a Wear Application.

In case 1 you could generate Notification from your android(phone) application,you dont need to write codes for watch.Into that notification we can provide PendingIntent. http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

In case 2 , After creating wearable Application and including button.But we cant provide Intent (to open activity inside phone) inside on_click.The Wearable Data Layer API, which is part of Google Play services, provides a communication channel for your handheld and wearable apps.By using Message Api/Data Api we are communicating to phone to start an activity.Suppose when ever we are sending Message with some appropiate data (from wear to phone) by that button click, onMessageRecieved method will be triggered in phone with in that method you could provide some Intent and Start Activity.
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html